# What's the word for learning the wrong thing?

Tags: single-word-requests

There's a word like mis-learning or mis-training where rather than learning something correct, you learn something incorrect.

For example, if you were learning English as a second language, and constantly read people using [alot](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html) a lot, and as a result used that word, even after you found out the correct spelling because of habit or muscle memory, what would that be called?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear to me. You already know about the word "mislearn" but are asking for the word when people *knowingly continue to use what they have mislearnt* ?

Comment: @JoseK: Is it less confusing now?

Comment: How about trying the word: maleducation?

Comment: related: [Is there a word or term to describe mispronouncing a word due to someone else's accent?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/236803/is-there-a-word-or-term-to-describe-mispronouncing-a-word-due-to-someone-elses)

Answer (score 5):

That could possibly be called ["mislearning":](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Mislearn)

> Mis`learn´
>   v. t.   1.  To learn wrongly.

Answer (score 2):

The answer you are looking for is [here](https://www.thesisscientist.com/docs/Summaries/cd8cbacb-9ab2-4499-b900-c009ad6719a2):

**Fossilisation** (noun):
The process in which incorrect language becomes a habit and cannot easily be corrected. For example, a B2 learner might
habitually not add an ‘s’ when saying third person singular present simple verbs. Learners at this level do not usually make this
mistake, but, for this learner, the error was not corrected early and it has become habitual.

<sup>www.thesisscientist.com</sup>

Comment: Please provide a link for where you got that definition from. Plagiarism (copying other people's content without providing attribution) is not welcome on ELU.

Answer (score 0):

RETARDING

That learning a particular subject correctly ADVANCES ones knowledge so it stands to reason learning it wrong would certainly be the opposite, simply put, RETARDING

Answer (score -2):

Imparting into someone, the Truth, is called "education".
Imparting into someone, a Belief, is called "indoctrination".
The hard part is knowing the difference.

Comment: This is a question of idology. The OP was asking for a word for being misinformed. as such, you are not really addressing the OP's question.

Comment: Perhaps I should spell it out.  "mis-learning or mis-training" is "indoctrination".  (I won't object if you just call it "lying".)  "learning something" is the "education" part, where "correct" references the Truth. "learn something incorrect" requires belief to accept.  PS: I liked it better the first way.

Comment: You can spell 'til the cows come home. You're still wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion.  You obviously have very strong beliefs.
PS: It's spelled "IDEOLOGY"...

Comment: It's not indoctrination unless it's systematic and intentional. From the [free dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/indoctrinate): "1. to teach (a person or group of people) systematically to accept doctrines, esp uncritically". It also doesn't necessarily need to be false or even misleading (*especially* uncritically).